# Kinda bi-directional dependencies with Maven or am I just confused?

Tags: maven, pom.xml, dependency-management, m2e, circular-dependency

I'm trying to convert a project with several submodules to Maven, but I think I'm a bit confused about **how** to do it right.

It's a webapp with `war` packaging. So here's our project structure:

- `core` (with spring, hibernate, etc.)
- `module1`
- `module2`
- `module3`

Every `module` depends on `core`, because `core` provides database access and some basic functionality. In words of Maven, I'd put

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>a.b.c</groupId>
  <artifactId>core</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

inside every `module`'s `pom.xml`.

Next: `module3` also depends on `module1`. So I'd put

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>a.b.c</groupId>
  <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

inside `module3`'s `pom.xml`.

---

Until here everything looks pretty straight and normal I think (?!). **Now the confusing stuff:**

- `core` is the webapp. So at the end I'd compile the `core` project.
- those `modules` will provide some extra functionality for the webapp

  - This means: `core` somehow depends on every `module`
- A future release may not contain `module2` but instead `module2b`, which in fact inherits the classes of `module2`, but can add/overwrite some functionality

At the moment we have a properties (and an additional xml) file which contains the `modules` inside the `core` project. The contents of this file tell Spring to scan a few more packages for Controllers and Beans.

Additionally there's an Ant task, which works with filesystem paths:

```
<path id="libs.projects">
    <dirset dir="${basedir}/../.">
        <include name="libprefix*"/>
        <exclude name="moduleprefix*"/>
    </dirset>
</path>
```

It scans for folders beginning with `libprefix` and `moduleprefix` and compiles them. Afterwards it takes the generated `jar` files from the target directories and some other files (html, jsp, js, css, etc.) and copies them into the `core` projects directories.

---

The questions are pretty clear, I think:

- What's the optimal project layout (especially concerning those future releases)
- Is bi-directional project dependency the right way?

Maybe there's some other way using a Maven parent module with `pom` packaging? I never before used this and don't know it's capabilities. But I hope you guys know how to solve this ;)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In Maven, if you want to make your future easy, you will have each Maven project generate one thing. One jar. One war. One whatever.

This is seldom easy when transitioning an existing project to Maven. The problem is not so much with Maven as with the existing project which may have never had the dependency structure organized. It may already be convoluted with parts dependent on other part's sub-pieces and so forth. It may look circular but that is usually just a failure to properly analyze and sub-divide the bits in a useful way. The existing project may be sort of like my garage. I can find anything but I sure can't describe how its organized to anyone else. This may be appropriate for a garage or a small one-person project but for a large project with code performing valuable services, it just isn't appropriate. Maven makes it hard on you to leave it disorganized. Any build tool can work with it when organized.

You are not doing this one-project/one-artifact thing, I think, based on what you said:

1. 'core' contains the shared code used by the modules AND 'core' is the webapp (That sounds like it may have two purposes.)
2. there is an Ant task that generates a jar and copies it to the core project (A jar should be created by its own project upon which core would be dependent.)

Some possible solutions.

- The Ant task needs to be its own project that generates its own jar file WHILE the core project depends on that jar.
- There is another war project that collects up the jars generated in the various modules and the core that creates the web app.
- Perhaps you need multiple war projects if your discussion about module 2b means there is another version of the web app that uses module 2b instead of module 2.
- Perhaps the discussion about module 2b is solved with versioning of the modules if you quit using module 2 when you move on to using module 2b.

Its got to be rethought as a top-level artifact (a war, perhaps) that depends on some lower-level artifacts (module jars and the core jar, maybe). Then those lower-level artifacts depend on other low level artifacts. Everything can depend on 3rd party jars, too.

Comment: Sounds good. So if I understood right: **one** `war` project with spring (and web stuff), which depends on `jar` project `database` which has hibernate. Then each `module` will depend on the `database` project. And the `war` project will depend on all needed `modules`? ... Then if we want a 2nd release of the app with different config, we'll create a 2nd `war` project, which depends on all modules which are needed. Right?

Comment: But then there's still one thing left: Each `module` has its own `Entities` and `DAOs`. This means they have to get included in `persistence.xml`. But I don't want to include them in the `database` project. The database project **should** look around in the other modules for those classes. Is this possible?

Comment: Does this help: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-jpa-multiple-pu